# Incorrect Month To Date in member dashboard

Tags: civimember, dashboard

Member Dashboard shows following headings

```
October – (Last Month)  March (MTD) 2018 (YTD)
```

Obviously the month to date heading should be "November" rather than "March".

Where is civicrm getting its current month from?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. I've logged an issue here along with a fix See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/511